# Can I install Ubuntu Studio on a Chromebook?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, chrome-book

Just curious, seeing as how it's a "creative" OS, I don't know how functional it could be on Chromebook.

Can I install Ubuntu Studio on a Chromebook?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

Can you install Ubuntu Studio on your particular model of Chromebook, I couldn't possibly know.

Will all the included applications perform up to your needs? I couldn't possible know.

Ubuntu Studio is just Ubuntu with select pre-installed applications. I have a similarly built OS based on Ubuntu running on my CR-48 Chromebook.

There are 2 main ways of running a full Linux OS on Chromebook, Crouton which does not remove ChromeOS, and a full install.

If you are not ready to get rid of ChromeOS, look into [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton),
 or [chrx](https://chrx.org/).

If you want to go all the way with a full install and remove ChromeOS, you need to install a new BIOS before booting your install media and installing as normal.
I would actually recommend using something like [GalliumOS](https://galliumos.org/) which is based on Ubuntu and designed for use on Chromebooks. You could then install the same apps as Ubuntu Studio has.

Even if using a standard Ubuntu Studio install image, much of the documentation from GalliumOS wiki will apply, like this [install page](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing).

Comment: Thank you! so, how is it done? All the instructions I can find are limited to KDE (which doesn't work well), Unity, or xfce.

Comment: Updated to add info on getting started.

Comment: So I have GalliumOS installed for dual boot, and it prompts "ctrl L for GalliumOS" but when I do that, it doesn't work, it just beeps. Any solution or recommendations?

Comment: Sorry, I've never done dual boot.